# Showing nested screens in Google Analytics for Mobile

Tags: mobile, google-analytics

I have an app that has nesting similar to a web page. For example:

- Navigation Page

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3

I am passing this in as a screen view like this: "Page/Item 1"

My hope was that Analytics would parse that so that on the root Screens page, I would see "Page" and all of the associated Views rolled up into that. Then, clicking on Page would show me all of the stats on the individual Details pages.

Unfortunately, Analytics interprets "Page/Item 1" literally, so I have a very cluttered listing with:

- Page/Item 1
- Page/Item 4
- Page/Item 2

Is there a way to get this to work how I intend? Or are screens always going to be literal and never show nesting as a web site would?